# How to increase title font size on axs[i].title.set_text

Tags: python, fonts

I'm using Pythons matplotlib and this is my code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(10,10, figsize=(100, 100))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .005, wspace= .1)
axs = axs.ravel()
for i, img in enumerate(glob.glob('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Tensorflow/0_180_direction_indicator/*.jpg')):
    image = cv2.imread(img)
    axs[i].axis('off')
    axs[i].imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    axs[i].title.set_text(img[-13:-4] ,fontsize= 50)
```

But it shows

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

in

```
  6     axs[i].axis('off')

  7     axs[i].imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

----> 8     axs[i].title.set_text(img[-13:-4] ,fontsize= 50)

TypeError: set_text() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fontsize'

Comment: try `axs[i].set_title(img[-13:-4],fontsize= 50)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this syntax

```
axes[0].set_title("title",fontsize=50)
```